# SQL condition for ordering base on a group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to order some data, base in the StockID being 3 and also having two warehouse in this case the WarehouseId 1 and 13,

```
select ProductID, WarehouseID, StockID
from @allStocksState 
group by ProductID, WarehouseID, StockID
order by CASE WHEN StockID = 3 then 0
             else 1 
         end
```

Result:

```
7002    13  3
7003    1   3
7003    13  3
7012    1   3
7012    13  3
6995    1   3
7020    13  3
7031    13  3
7045    1   3
7045    13  3
7046    1   3
7046    13  3
```

So in the case of 6995,7020,7031 Should appear at the end since in this case they only have one WarehouseId each, so what changes to my query do i need to apply? any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select ProductID, WarehouseID, StockID
from @allStocksState 
group by ProductID, WarehouseID, StockID
order by count(*) over (partition by productid) desc,
         (case when StockID = 3 then 0 else 1 end);
```

The `count(*) over (partition by productid)` counts how many rows have the same `productid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ProductID,WarehouseID,StockID from @allStocksState 
    group by ProductID,WarehouseID,StockID
    order by CASE WHEN StockID=3 then
    "ASC" else
    "DESC" end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add some context/explanation, as code only answers do not fulfill our standards. See [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).